# fabricjs - creating endless animation loop without lags

Tags: javascript, animation, fabricjs

I am trying to create an endless animation loop of rotation with FabricJS. It works like this: the `rotate` function gets animation details (object to animate, duration of one animation loop, starting angle of rotation) as parameters, and invokes inner function `rotateInner` to launch the animation itself. `rotateInner` rotates given object using [`fabric.util.animate`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.util.html#.animate) with linear easing function (to make rotation speed constant) to run one animation loop and to invoke itself after the loop ends, which results in an infinite animation loop.

The problem is that `rotateInner` lags every time between animation loops when it invokes itself through [`fabric.util.animate`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.util.html#.animate).

For example, I use animation loop with duration = 1 second and rotation angle = 180 degrees. In that case, animation makes lag every 1 second after rotating by 180 degrees.

**I've found a solution to make lag occur N times less**. Instead of rotating by **180 degrees for 1 second**, I rotate object by **180*N degrees for N seconds**. If I pick enough big N, the user will meet lag **potentially never**. But only **potentially**.

What are reasons of lags and **is it possible to remove lags between animation loops completely? Or, perhaps, I went wrong way, and I should use something completely different to create endless animation loop?**

[Here's example which demonstrates lag (on jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/minddigger/hx1uovp9/3/). (The rotate function has additional argument - multiplier. It's **N** I've just wrote about above) Left rectangle rotates 180 degrees per  800 milliseconds, and the right rectangle rotates 180*10 degrees per 800*10 milliseconds, and thus the right one rotates quicker than the left one.

And, if you don't want to use jsfiddle or if example became inaccessible for some reason, here's the example itself in code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
    <style>canvas {border: 5px dotted black;}</style>
    <title>FabricJS animation loop lag</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="700" height="300"></canvas>

    <script>
        var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('mycanvas');

        var rectCreationOptions = {
            left: canvas.getWidth()/4,
            top: canvas.getHeight()/2,
            fill: '#0bb',
            width: canvas.getWidth()/5,
            height: canvas.getHeight()/5,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center'
        };

        // creating left rectangle:
        var rect1 = new fabric.Rect(rectCreationOptions);

        rectCreationOptions.left *= 3;

        // creating right rectangle:
        var rect2 = new fabric.Rect(rectCreationOptions);

        canvas.add(rect1);
        canvas.add(rect2);

        function rotate(animatedObject, duration = 1000, multiplier = 1, startAngle = 0) {
            duration *= multiplier;
            var addAngle = 180 * multiplier;
            (function rotateInner(startAngle) {
                fabric.util.animate({
                    startValue: startAngle,
                    endValue: startAngle+addAngle,
                    duration: duration,
                    // linear easing function:
                    easing: function(t, b, c, d) { return c*t/d + b; },
                    onChange: function (value) {
                        animatedObject.angle = value;
                        canvas.renderAll();
                    },
                    onComplete: function() {
                        rotateInner(startAngle+addAngle);
                    }
                });
            })(startAngle);
        }

        rotate(rect1, 800, 1); // lags every 800 ms
        rotate(rect2, 800, 10); // lags every 800*10 ms
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I will be thankful for help.
Please, don't throw rotten tomatoes at me if I made tiny mistake. This is my first question on stackoverflow. :)
Best wishes everyone.